# The attr() method does not work correctly in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I've got some trouble in Internet Explorer 7 with this code:

```
$('<input/>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', class: 'server_list', value: server_list[i]}).appendTo('.server-content');
$('<label/>', { 'for': server_list, class: 'server_list_text', text: " " + server_list[i] }).appendTo('.server-content');
```

This gives me an error...

> id, chaine or number expected

...on the first line

What should I do? I need this to create a dynamic list. The code above works fine in Mozilla Firefox.

Ty

Comment: `class` is a reserved word. Replace with `className`.

Comment: the property `class` could be the culprit

Comment: `$('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    className: 'server_list',
    value: server_list[i]
}).appendTo('.server-content');`

Comment: Putting `class` in quotes should also work.

Comment: u're fast ! it's work, thanks u so much !